# how to delegate replies in a web app

Tags: message-queue

We have created a web app that sends messages. sending part is straight forward.. but when we receive the replies, how can I delegate the messages sent? How can I know which message is for the certain user? What I have in mind is to keep a hashmap that stores an object that the users can retrieve.. is this ok? Do I have to create a received message queue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need a received message queue as most web containers should be multithreaded to handle multiple requests.

The central hashmap object is a good idea for managing different client connections, but you need to be sure to watch for Concurrency issues and thread safety issues.  As long as you use a thread safe data structure, the application web container should be able to handle managing queuing up the requests so that you don't have to.

As a side note, it sounds like a Comet library may be helpful to you for server push and to make sure messages are pushed to the correct parties/client connections.

Comment: The thing is we did not use any message oriented middleware. We created a queue and connected it to netty. We are using grails so I created a Service that stores the objects that sends the messages. Is this ok?